# solve the equation $(z+1)^3+i(z-1)^3=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have to solve $(z+1)^3+i(z-1)^3=0$ I tried it in many ways.but I couldn't come up with an answer.can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: try using $z=re^(i\theta)$ then expand $(a-b)^3$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\implies\left(\dfrac{z+1}{z-1}\right)^3=-i=i^3$$

$$\iff\dfrac{z+1}{z-1}=iw$$  where $w$ is a cube root of unity

Now apply componendo & dividendo

Answer (score 2):

Verify that $z=-1$ is not a solution so you can safely divide by $(z+1)^3.$ This gives you three possible values for $(z-1)/(z+1).$ Solve this last equation by a conformal mapping.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$(z+1)^3+i(z-1)^3=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(1+i)z^3+(3-3i)z^2+(3+3i)z+(1-i)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(1+i)(z+i)(z^2-4iz-1)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$(z+i)(z^2-4iz-1)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$z+i=0\space\space\vee\space\space z^2-4iz-1=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint assume $z=x+iy$ then $(z+1)^3+i(z-1)^3=0$ becomes $(x+iy)^3+3(x+iy)^2+3(x+iy)+1+i[(x+iy)^3-3(x+iy)^2+3(x+iy-1)]$ solve it comparing real and imaginary part with $0,0i$ you get $(x,y)$ . I know its messy ! Hope its clear.