# Help With Finding The Sum of all The Square Roots of a Complex Number Equation

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Hello everyone I have to find the sum of all the square roots answers of the equation $(z + 1)^n = (z - 1)^n$.

I tried to use a = $z +1 , b = z -1$ and place $a^n - b^n = 0 = (a-b)(a^{n-1} + a^{n-2}b + ... + b^{n-1})$

And invert this to a polynomial and use Vieta's formula for finding the sum of all the square roots answers but I didn't success

someone can help me please?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607487/the-roots-of-the-equation-zn-1zn and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562603/solve-the-equation-z13iz-13-0

Comment: What is the exact wording of the question you are asked to solve? The way you are asking isn't that clear. Do you want the sum of the squares of the roots of the polynomial or sum of the "square roots" of the roots of the polynomial?

Comment: The sum of the squares of the polynomial. I meant if $x_1 , x_2 , x_3 , ... , x_n$ are the roots of the polynomial so I need to find $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^n + ... + x_n^2$

Comment: In that case, you just need to expand the difference $(z+1)^n - (z-1)^n$ to the form $2n (z^{n-1} - A z^{n-2} + B z^{n-3} + \cdots)$ using binomial theorem. By Vieta's formula, the sum you want equals to $A^2 - 2B$

Comment: What is A and what is B?

Comment: Someone can post an answer or hint please?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Since $z\ne 1$ and $z\ne -1$, you can write $$({z+1\over z-1})^n=1$$hence all the roots of the equation can be obtained from $${z+1\over z-1}=e^{j{2\pi\over n}k}\quad,\quad k=0,1,\cdots n-1$$

Comment: Can you solve all the question please?

Comment: Did you make some try after the hint?

Comment: I didn't understand what you do?

Comment: Because $1$ and $-1$ are not among the roots of the equation, you can divide both sides of the equation to $(z-1)^n$. The equation is reduced to $u^n=1$ which is a famous equation with roots being equal to $e^{jk{2\pi\over n}}$. You can conclude this result by using the polar notation of $u$ as $u=re^{j\phi}$