# Solving $(z+i)^n+(z-i)^n=0$

Tags: complex-numbers, binomial-theorem

> Given a complex number $z$, how can I solve $$(z+i)^n+(z-i)^n=0$$ for z?

My attempt

I thought that I couldn't possibly convert this into Euler's format. So, I took to Binomial Theorem.
$$(z+i)^n+(z-i)^n=0$$
Using binomial theorem,
$$2\left[{n \choose 0}z^n+{n \choose 2}z^{n-2}i^2+{n \choose 4}z^{n-4}i^4+...\right]=0$$
$${n \choose 2}z^{n-2}+{n\choose 6}z^{n-6}+...={n \choose 0}z^{n}+{n \choose 4}z^{n-4}+...$$
How can I solve this after this step?

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Rewrite as $\frac{z + i}{z - i} = (-1)^{\frac{1}{n}}$. So the question essentially boils down to finding the $n^{th}$ roots of -1. Think you can do that?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607487/the-roots-of-the-equation-zn-1zn  OR https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1562603/solve-the-equation-z13iz-13-0

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Not the same. That has nth roots of 1, this has nth roots of $-1$.

Comment: $n^{th}$ roots of $-1$ are $cis (\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{n} )$ for $k = 0, 1, ... n - 1$.

Comment: @Kaind, I've given two examples , one has $1$ and the other $-i$

Comment: Geometrically, $|z+i|=|z-i|$ implies $z$ is real. Substituting $z+i=re^{i\theta}$ yields $\cos(n\theta)=0$ (and also $r=\csc\theta$ by drawing a right triangle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving:

$$\begin{align}y&=\frac{z+i}{z-i }\\
yz-yi&=z+i \\
(y-1)z&=(y+1)i \\
z&=\frac{iy+i}{y-1}    
\end{align}$$

Then you need $y^n=-1.$